# How to remove text from caption in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I put a table (with a caption) in a new section. I wanted to move the table down the page, so I added some new lines to the front of the caption. I then changed the style of the new lines from "Caption" to "Normal". When I insert references to the caption, however, the references include all the new lines characters. Very annoying! How can I remove those new line characters from the caption?

Comment: Is it a caption or title and alt text? Title and alt text are modified in the Tablet Properties dialog.

Comment: It is a caption, created by using the "Insert Caption..." dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to perhaps delete the caption and recreate it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-format-or-delete-captions-in-Word-82FA82A4-F0F3-438F-A422-34BB5CEF9C81

To **delete** a caption select it with your mouse and press the Delete key.

Comment: I ended up cutting the table, inserting the newlines I wanted, then pasting the table back in. That way I got newlines that weren't part of the caption.